# Moving files from common directory to different folders with same names

Tags: python

I have Folder 1 with files "Note 1", "Note 2", "Note 3". I would like to move these to Folder 2 with folders Note 1, Note 2 and Note 3 in it. So for example file "Note 1" will go to Folder 2> Note 1 folder. I would like to write code that recognizes the words "Note 1" in the file in Folder 1, then puts "Note 1" into Note 1 folder in Folder 2.

I'm new to coding (esp in Python). So far I'm not sure how to make it recognize the words "Note 1"/"Note 2". I know there are commands that will recognize the start/end of a word, but keep in mind the examples I have given are much simplified versions of what I need to work with: eg:"reg_001_0213_"word to recognize"_cyc2.tif"

Comment: `if "Note 1" in filename:` or `if "note 1" in filename.lower():`

Comment: `os.makedirs(directory, exists_ok=True)` and `shutil.copy(filename, directory)`

Answer (score 1):

To check if substring exists in string (in filename)

```
if "Note 1" in filename:
```

or if it may have lower and upper case chars

```
if "note 1" in filename.lower():
```

To copy file to another folder and keep its name you can use

```
shutil.copy("old_directory/filename", "new_directory")
```

but first you have to create folder if doesn't exists

```
if not os.path.exists(new_directory):
    os.makedirs(new_directory)
```

In newest Python you can use `exist_ok=True` and it will not raise exception if directory already exist - so you don't have to check `os.path.exists`.

```
os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)
```

---

More: standard modules [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#module-shutil), [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#module-os), [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html), [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

---

**EDIT:**

To get names in folder

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    print(filename)
```

To concatenate filename to directory's name

```
path = os.path.join(directory, filename)

path = os.path.join(directory1, directory2, filename)
```

Using pathlib

```
dir = pathlib.Path( directory )

path = dir / filename

path = dir / directory2 / filename
```

To get names in folder and subfolders

```
for root, files, dirs in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are actually obtaining the file names using Python's `os.listdir()` or `os.scandir()`.

Are the file names ALWAYS in the format `reg_001_0213_<word to recognize>_cyc2.tif`?  If so, you can "tokenize" the file name by using the `split()` method of strings.  You get back a list of smaller strings, with the string supplied to `split()` used as a delimiter.  Example:

```
>>> fname = "reg_001_0213_<word to recognize>_cyc2.tif"
>>> tokens = fname.split("_")
>>> tokens
['reg', '001', '0213', '<word to recognize>', 'cyc2.tif']
>>> word_to_recognize = tokens[3]
>>> word_to_recognize
'<word to recognize>'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And yes, they're usually in the same format but the "word to recognize" is different in each

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
import os

OLD_DIR = './old'
NEW_DIR = './new'

for file_name in os.listdir(OLD_DIR):
    old_file = os.path.join(OLD_DIR, file_name)
    if file_name.count('_') != 4:
        print(f'ignoring {old_file}')
        continue
    _, _, _, token, _ = file_name.split('_')
    new_path = os.path.join(NEW_DIR, token)
    os.makedirs(new_path, exist_ok=True)
    new_file = os.path.join(new_path, file_name)
    print(f'moving {old_file} to {new_file}')
    os.rename(old_file, new_file)
```

## Output

```
moving ./old/reg_001_0213_token1_cyc2.tif to ./new/token1/reg_001_0213_token1_cyc2.tif
moving ./old/reg_001_0213_token2_cyc2.tif to ./new/token2/reg_001_0213_token2_cyc2.tif
ignoring ./old/foo
```

See:

- [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [str.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)
- [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)
- [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)
- [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)
- [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename)